# Is a question about 'how to compare languages for this purpose' on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

Are questions which ask for ways or methods on how to compare the design or elements of two languages on-topic? For example, a person might ask:

> What are some ways to compare programming languages in terms of how useful they are to beginner developers?

Or:

> How could you compare two languages from the perspective of an app developer?

Comment: [This question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/923/133) was fundamentally about techniques for measuring and possibly comparing languages, though much more specific than these, but is very controversially open (closed 5-2, left closed 3-1, reopened 3-2). I think an even broader one would have a very hard time, albeit the first one is broadly in scope of CSED work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are some ways to compare programming languages in terms of how useful they are to beginner developers?

Needs more focus, and unclear: do you mean comparing how useful the languages are for beginners, or how useful the "ways to compare" are for beginners? But either way, too broad. There could be a hundred different answers to either of those questions.

> How could you compare two languages from the perspective of an app developer?

Needs more focus. Better than the other one, though.

---

The thing is, there are many different aspects in which programming languages can vary, and potentially several ways of comparing languages along each dimension. For a more focused question, you could pick one aspect and ask about ways to measure that; or you could pick a target audience (e.g. smartphone app developers) and just ask *what* aspects of a programming language are most significant for that audience without also asking how to compare languages on those aspects.

This isn't to say that a question like either of the above would definitely be on-topic, but at least it's more likely to be focused enough to be answerable in our Q&A format.